# Attaching an s3 file to an smtplib lib email using MIMEApplication

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, mime

I have a django application that would like to attach files from an S3 bucket to an email using smtplib and email.mime libraries.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication

# This takes the files and attaches each one within the bucket to the email. The server keeps erroring on the "with open(path,'rb') as fil" .

def attach_files(path_to_aws_bucket,msg,files=[]):

    for f in files or []:
        path = path_to_aws_bucket + f
        with open(path,'rb') as fil:
            msg.attach(MIMEApplication(
                fil.read(),
                Content_Disposition='attachment; filename="{}"' .format(os.path.basename(f)),
                Name=os.path.basename(f)
            ))

    return msg

def build_message(toaddress,fromaddress,subject,body):

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['To'] = toaddress
    msg['From'] = fromaddress
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    b = u"{}" .format(body)
    content = MIMEText(b.encode('utf-8') ,'html','UTF-8')

    msg.attach(content)

    return msg


def send_gmail(msg,username,password,fromaddress,toaddress):

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username,password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddress, toaddress , msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Python can't open the file because it claims that whatever s3 url I give it is not a valid directory. All of my permissions are correct. I tried using urllib.opener to open the file and attach it however it also threw an error.

Not sure where to go from here and was wondering if anyone has done this before. Thanks!

Comment: How are you connected to s3 in your django/python environment?  Are you mapping a local directory to the s3 bucket?  The python open function is expecting to read off the local filesystem, not s3.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using S3 get_object instead of smtplib?

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
import boto3

msg = MIMEMultipart()
new_body = "asdf"
text_part = MIMEText(new_body, _subtype="html")
msg.attach(text_part)

filename='abc.pdf'
msg["To"] = "amal@gmail.com"
msg["From"] = "amal@gmail.com"
s3_object = boto3.client('s3', 'us-west-2')
s3_object = s3_object.get_object(Bucket=‘bucket-name’, Key=filename)
body = s3_object['Body'].read()

part = MIMEApplication(body, filename)
part.add_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.attach(part)
ses_aws_client = boto3.client('ses', 'us-west-2')
ses_aws_client.send_raw_email(RawMessage={"Data" : msg.as_bytes()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using urllib works for me, look at the following, I have this Lambda function to send emails with smtplib:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr
import urllib
# ['subject','from', 'from_name','to','cc','body','smtp_server','smtp_user','smtp_password']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = event['subject']
    msg['From'] = formataddr((str(Header(event['from_name'], 'utf-8')), event['from']))
    msg['To'] = event['to']
    msg['Cc'] = event['cc'] # this is comma separated field 

    # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
    text = "Look in a browser or on a mobile device this HTML msg"
    html = event['body']

    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

    # Attach parts into message container.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
    # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

    # Attach files from S3
    opener = urllib.URLopener()
    myurl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/file_name.pdf"
    fp = opener.open(myurl)

    filename = 'file_name.pdf'
    att = MIMEApplication(fp.read(),_subtype="pdf")
    fp.close()
    att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=filename)
    msg.attach(att)

    # Create de SMTP Object to Send
    s = smtplib.SMTP(event['smtp_server'], 587)
    s.login(event['smtp_user'], event['smtp_password'])
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], [msg['To']], msg.as_string())

    return True
```